# keep user from going to other view ui-route

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I am trying to add some sort of resolve/promise to this to keep the user from moving on to certain pages until they have created a profile, added a friend, etc. I have an app, a controller, and a service. Any guidance would be helpful!

```js
var app = angular.module('socialInternApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider

//#1 Initial Page
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/templates/home.html'
        })

//#2 Landing Page(new users' profile page) - User is taken here when they submit the initial form on the Home page.
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            templateUrl: '/views/templates/landing.html'
        })
//#3 Search for Friends - User can access this page only after they submit the initial form on the Home Page.
        .state('friend-search', {
            url: '/friend-search',
            templateUrl: '/views/templates/friend-search.html',
            controller: 'friendSearchCtrl'
        })
//#4 Upadte Profile Information - User can access this as soon as they submit the initial form on the Home page.
        .state('update', {
            url: '/update',
            templateUrl: 'views/templates/update.html',
        })
//#5 Other users' profile page. User is taken here after clicking button on image overlay on the friend-search page.
        .state('friend-profile', {
          url: '/friend-profile/:id',
          templateUrl: 'views/templates/friend-profile.html',
          controller: 'friendProfileCtrl'
        })
//#6 New users' friends list. Only can access after they have added a friend.
        .state('friends', {
            url: '/friends',
            templateUrl: '/views/templates/friends.html'
        });
  });
```

Controller code:

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $state, mainSvrc){

  $scope.$state = $state;
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    // Check whether user input form is submitted
    if(!formSubmitted){
     event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
//Local storage for new user profile and updated profile.//
  $scope.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

  var formSubmitted = false;
  $scope.createUser = function(obj, $event) {
    $scope.currentUser = mainSvrc.createUser(obj);
    formSubmitted = true;
    $state.go('landing');
    swal(
      '',
      'Your Information has been saved!',
      'success'
      );
  };
});
```

Service Code:

```js
app.service('mainSvrc', function() {

//Stores users' data in local storage after clicking the save button on either form.
  this.createUser = function(user) {
    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(user));
    return user;
  };
```

HTML code:

```html
<form class="form-home">
                <input type="text"
                ng-model="newUser.name"
                placeholder="Full Name"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Full Name'" />

                <input type="text"
                ng-model="newUser.tagline"
                placeholder="Tagline"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Tagline'">

                <input type="text"
                ng-model="newUser.profileUrl"
                placeholder="Profile Image Url"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Profile Image Url'">

                <textarea rows="15" cols="50"
                ng-model="newUser.bio"
                placeholder="Bio"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Bio'">
                </textarea>

                <button type="submit" ng-click="createUser(newUser, event)"
                >
                    Save Changes
                </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you show your controller and view code?

Comment: You can use $locationChangeStart to trigger the URL change event and to prevent user from renavigation

Comment: You have different links "View Friends", "Find Friends" etc.. and you have templates for these. Can you show the controller code associated with these templates.

Comment: @RaviTeja not sure if all of it was needed, but I put it in, just in case you provide more insight. Essentially what I can't get to work is that when someone is on 'Home' I don't want them to be able to go to 'Find Friends' until they submit the input form. Then when they are on 'Find Friends' I don't want them to be able to go to 'View Friends' until they have added a friend.

Thanks for your continued help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$stateChangeStart`event to check whether form is submitted or not.

`$stateChangeStart` event triggers each time you try to navigate to a different page, in you case `$state.go('landing')`.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  // Check whether user input form is submitted
  if(!formSubmitted){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I believe, you should be having a `ng-click` event when form submit button is clicked.
So, inside the `function` associated with that click event set `formSubmitted` variable to `true`.

For Example:

```
var formSubmitted = false;
$scope.createUser = function(profileObj, $event) {
    // I don't  think you need to preventDefault here, but not sure what you are trying to do. 
    // If you just wrote the $event.preventDefault() so that user will not be navigated to landing page, you don't need it here.
    //$event.preventDefault();
    $scope.userProfile = profileObj;
    userProfService.createUser(profileObj);
    formSubmitted = true;
    $state.go('landing');
    swal(
        'Welcome to the Club!',
        'Your Information has been saved!',
        'success'
    );
};
```

Comment: where do i put the $scope.$on code block? I tried putting it in my app and my controller but it just erases my veiws

Comment: What do you mean by "erases my views"? You should have the $on block inside controller function associated with your current view

Comment: Can you also check your browser console and see whether there are any errors. If so, then update your question with a screenshot of that error and complete `code` in the `file` that error is pointing to in the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Let me clean up my code a bit. I have been working this and if I can't get it to work after some trial and error, I will get back to you. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have edited all my code with the code you suggested and I now my form does not appear on the page. There are no errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

You Could use the `$locationChangeStart` event in angular js to validate the exit event of the user from a controller.

```
  $scope.IsUserNavigatable = function(){
     var createdUsers = $scope.UserList;
     var isUserCreated = createdUsers.length > 0;
     return isUserCreated;
  }

  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

        if ($scope.IsUserNavigatable() ) {
            //Here the user can move to next page
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
  });
```

The `$locationChangeStart` event will be triggered on the user trying the change the URL. On validating the navigation condition, the user can be redirected to another page. `$scope.IsUserNavigatable()` refers to your method that validates the navigation condition of the user. If that fails, prevent the user navigation by triggering `event.preventDefault()`

Here I have shown a sample function to check whether a user have been created or not while exiting from the page. In that function it returns the Length of user list created at that time. The user can navigate if the length of the user array is greater than zero.

Comment: Can you expand on the code? I have implemented it and it doesn't seem to be working. I am assuming it is because I don't have it on my app but in my controller.